# How to disable usage of certain ES2015 features with ESLint 2?

Tags: javascript, eslint

In ESLint 1, I can use the `ecmaFeatures` option to disable or enable certain language features. E.g.

```
ecmaFeatures:
  defaultParams:  false
```

Above config disables `defaultParams`.

This is very useful because in runtime like Node, not all features are available, and I don't want to use a transpiler.

But in ESLint 2, that was removed. You only got `ecmaVersion`, which doesn't alerting on usage of ES2015 features at all even if you give it a `ecmaVersion` of 5. I guess this make sense since the JavaScript interpreter will complain about the usage of unsupported syntax at interpretation time, but what about developing for browsers have different level of ES2015 support? Syntax that works for Chrome won't work for IE9.

**Is there any way to lint the usage of language features, e.g. disable destructuring?**

Comment: I think if you want cross-browser support these days, you'll have to transpile anyway. If you only want to target specific browser versions, you probably can test in these right away to see whether they complain.

Comment: @Bergi I will surely do that, but it would be nice to have the option to limit language feature usage. E.g. in Node 4, it has half of the ES2015 features.

Comment: The rules section should cover what you need. I don't see how a linter could stop anyone from actually using those features though. It acts as a warning, it does not impose usage.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Do you know a specific rule for this purpose?

Comment: There is no one rule. You'll have to "manually" set all features you need disabled to "off". Eslint does not care about browser support. It is not meant to do that. All it cares about is code compliance. I think Eslint is not the tool you need for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[no-restricted-syntax](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax) rule disallows specific syntax. This "syntax" is meaning the types of AST nodes. The spec of AST is here: https://github.com/estree/estree

[eslint-plugin-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-node)'s no-unsupported-features rule disallows unsupported ECMA features by specific Node's version. I don't know whether a similar rule for browsers exists or not.