# Is there an elegant way to tell eslint to ensure that we're not using any ES6 syntax / functions?

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, ecmascript-6, lint, eslint

Is there an elegant way to tell ESLint to ensure that we're not using any ES6 / EMCAScript 2015 syntax / functions?

I've found the following answer somewhat helpful but it seems that it doesn't take care of everything (e.g. I don't see how to catch the usage of Object.assign()):
 [How to disable usage of certain ES2015 features with ESLint 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436903/how-to-disable-usage-of-certain-es2015-features-with-eslint-2)

Comment: Curious to know what you ended up doing - I am trying to do the exact same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

[eslint-plugin-es5](https://github.com/nkt/eslint-plugin-es5) is the package dedicated to your use case. For example the rule `es5/no-es6-static-methods` forbids the usage of `Object.assign`.